# Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:3001/swagger_doc.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, swagger

I have my api ready.
now i want to integrate swagger with my api

I am using this gem `https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger-rails`

but i am getting error in browser console that

```
swagger-ui.min.js?body=1:9 GET http://localhost:3001/swagger_doc.json 404 (Not Found)

Unable to Load SwaggerUI
```

Help me to solve this 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set app_url for each request in before_action. It helped me. Just add code below to the config/initializers/swagger.rb

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.before_action do
  GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url = request.protocol + request.host_with_port
end

GrapeSwaggerRails.options.url = '/swagger_doc.json'
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url  = 'http://swagger.wordnik.com'
```